# Mock native objects

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, robolectric, jmockit, powermockito

I'm using Robolectric and Mockito for Unit Testing. The current setup is working out great for me but I have code that is heavily dependent on a library that is calling a native dependency. I'm aware that I cannot mock native method calls using Robolectric.

Is there a working example with Jmockit or PowerMock with Robolectric ? I've tried to use both libraries but failed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post the code that contains the object you want to mock?

Comment: I would isolate this library from your application with some wrapper